# Execution module function similar to 'file.managed'?

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to find an execution module that will allow me to pass a file through the Jinja templating engine and supply the arguments that should be replaced. There exists a `file.managed` *state* module that accomplishes this behavior:

```
my cool state:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://my/cool/file.xml
    - name: 'C:\Program Files\My dir\file.xml'
    - template: jinja
    - context:
      someVar: 'some value'
      another_var: 12345
```

However, I cannot find an *execution* module that can do this. There is [file.manage_file](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.manage_file) but it has a bunch of required arguments that I don't care about: `sfn`, `ret`, `source`, `source_sum`, `user`, `group`, `mode`, `attrs`, `saltenv`, `backup` -- `file.manage_file` will fail if you do not provide values for these.

The closest module function I've found is [cp.get_template](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.get_template) but it doesn't allow you to pass in `context` or `defaults`, so I've had to templatize my XML file to read in data from the pillar like so:

```
{%- from "map.jinja" import my_vars with context %}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <some-element>{{ my_vars.some-element }}</some-element>
  <another-thing>{{ my_vars.another-thing }}</another-thing>
</root>
```

This works, but then I can only render my XML with pillar data -- I want to be able to pass in variables when calling my execution module and use *those* variables to render my XML. Is there any way to accomplish this behavior with an execution module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using a combination of execution modules:

```
# Get template file
templateContent = __salt__['cp.get_file_str'](
   'salt://my/cool/file.xml'
)

# Render file with Jinja
renderedContent = __salt__['file.apply_template_on_contents'](
   contents = templateContent,
   template = 'jinja',
   saltenv = 'base',
   defaults = defaults,
   context = context
)

# Write the rendered file to disk
__salt__['file.write'](
   '/opt/some/path/on/minion/file.xml',
   renderedContent
)
```

Two things to consider:

`file.apply_template_on_contents` requires that you supply both the `defaults` and `context` args. This actually worked out pretty well for my use-case because I set defaults using values from a pillar that is applied to all minions, and `context` is the user-supplied overrides.

`cp.get_file_str` returns the file contents as a string -- I don't know how this would perform on a very large file, but for smaller configuration files I don't see an issue.